# How to list down Moodle 1.9 courses and integrate with other (PHP) system?

Tags: php, moodle

I want to get list of Moodle 1.9 courses. Which functions or api shall I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use OK Tech API, here is the link:

https://github.com/patrickpollet/moodlews/blob/master/wspp/mdl_baseserver.class.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use get_courses() function defined in the lib/datalib.php to get the list of all courses in the whole site or in category.